# Can I implement Groovy's getProperty in Java Objects

Tags: java, groovy

Can I implement Groovy's getProperty in Java Objects

I have a mixed Java/Groovy project, and I'm trying to add some "sugar" to my Java objects to make the Groovy side cleaner.

Is it possible to implement `Object getProperty(String)` in a Java class and have Groovy see it when accessing properties on that instance?

I have a failing test case as follows:

```
// HasProperty.java
public class HasProperty {
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        return "pie";
    }
}

// TestHasProperty.groovy
class HasPropertyTest {
    @org.junit.Test 
    public void testCanGetProperty() {
        def h = new HasProperty()
        assert h.name == "pie"
    }
}
```

The test fails without fanfare:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: HasProperty
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at [...]
```

This is Groovy 1.8.6 and Java 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work without implementing GroovyObject as per @tim_yates's answer, you can wrap the object with a very simple groovy object.  For example:

```
class GroovyWrapper extends groovy.util.Proxy {
    def wrapped
    GroovyWrapper(obj) {
        wrapped = obj
        adaptee = obj
    }
    def getProperty(String name) {
        wrapped.getProperty()
    }
}

def h = new GroovyWrapper(new HasProperty())
assert h.name == "pie"
```

Comment: I like this.  Simple and easy to grok.  Then just implement invokeMethod() to pass any other methods to the wrapped instance, and you've effectively implemented a full proxy.  Marking as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it, but I believe if you make your java class [implement GroovyObject](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_1_8_X/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyObject.java), or [extend GroovyObjectSupport](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_1_8_X/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyObjectSupport.java), you should be able to add a metaClass and this sort of dynamic property creation to your Java class...

Comment: I'm actually trying to keep Groovy off of the runtime classpath (we just use Groovy for unit/performance testing), so I'd like to avoid implementing/extending Groovy classes.

Comment: Rather than reflecting for Java classes containing certain method patterns, I think it just checks for implementation of specific groovy classes, so I'm not sure you can do it otherwise... Someone else may know differently though...

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Apache BeanUtils - http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/ there are some very useful utilities there that do this sort of thing.