# What is the difference between a Groovy object and a Java object with regards to functionality in Groovy code?

Tags: groovy

First of all, excuse me if I say something obvious because I did not research the answer to this question, it's just something that came to mind and couldn't find an answer to with a quick google search (I also don't know Groovy well).

I'm reading Groovy in action (1st ed) and in section 7.6 it states that "If you want a usual Java class to be recognized as a Groovy class, you only have to implement the GroovyObject interface. For convenience, you can also subclass the abstract class GroovyObjectSupport, which provides default implementations."

So I'm trying out some Java/Groovy (trying to find ways to make coding in Java faster/easier), and I'm instantiating this object Person, which is a Java object and the Person class does not have anything to do with Groovy (i.e. doesn't implement GroovyObject or anything). Person has a protected field, name, with getters/setters. I am able to access this like so in a groovy test case (extends GroovyTestCase), which btw is in a different package and should not be accessible like this:

```
Person person = new Person('joe')
println "Name: ${person.name}"
```

Isn't that using the meta info which a Groovy object would have i.e. Groovy would intercept, get the "name" part of "person.name" and call the getName() method or something like that? But person is a Java object... i.e. it shouldn't have that logic available.

I have not implemented GroovyObject or extended GroovyObjectSupport, yet it seems like this Java object has Groovy features I can use.

My question is, what can I assume from Java objects used in Groovy? There is obviously something being done behind the scenes to augment Java defined classes with some Groovy features... but, which features?

So, I guess my question boils down to: "What is done to Java classes when used within a Groovy context?"

Any info regarding the subject would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy indeed enhances your Java classes. The problem is when you want to use these enhanced Java classes from Java. Then you need to go for the `GroovyObject` and `GroovyObjectSupport` strategy.

About what you can expect, you can check the groovy docs:

- the [groovy-jdk](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) shows the Groovy enhancements to the JDK
- the [groovy-api](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi) shows the stuff specific from the Groovy library

Also the eclipse plugin works great in autocompleting your Java classes from Groovy.

---

Java objects are enhanced through Groovy's Meta Object Protocol (MOP), which intercepts and makes its own dispatch to methods and attributes. That is why you can intercept stuff and that's how new methods are added to Java's final classes.

The Groovy's MOP uses cached strategy and reflector classes to achieve a good performance.

Comment: Thanks for answering Will. Could you expand on "The problem is when you want to use these enhanced Java classes from Java". So ok, I can treat Java classes as if they were Groovy classes because Groovy enhances them with a default GroovyObject implementation. But in Java there are no enhanced Java classes to use because they are not enhanced i.e. the only reason I'm seeing to implement GroovyObject in Java is to get functionality in Groovy. Is there a use (in the context of Java) to implement GroovyObject?

Comment: I don't see any use, really. In a mixed project, i'd code mostly in Groovy :-). If you want to use Groovy funcionality in Java, you will need to  go for a strategy with either `groovy.util.Proxy` of `GroovySupport` or `GroovyObjectSupport`, and your calls will be a bit weird (like `object.getProperty("name")` instead of `object.name` or `object.getName()`). Here's a use of `GroovyObject`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364335/can-i-implement-groovys-getproperty-in-java-objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can also read Groovy objects via ObjectInputStream by overriding the resolveClass method and changing the class loader.
See http://www.feiteira.org/2013/04/reading-groovy-objects-from-java.html