# Marshalling/Unmarshalling Groovy Object using JAXB without annotation

Tags: java, xml, groovy, jaxb

i'm trying to do a library for an university project that make the marshalling/unmarshalling  for a Groovy object without any annotation on the marshalled object class.

Is there any problem using JAXB the same way i would use it for any Java object? Is there any limitations?

Thanks in advance, Giacomo

Comment: Do you mean *Groovy Object* in a sense of `GroovyObject` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518280/what-is-the-difference-between-a-groovy-object-and-a-java-object-with-regards-to)? If you have objects enhanced by groovy, there might be a problem using them from plain Java. See also [MOXy XML Bindings](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime003.htm) for JAXB without annotations.

Comment: I'm sorry about the ambiguity. I meant a generic object instantiated from a class written in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **No**.
Remember that ultimately Groovy objects are compiled into Java byte code. As a result, they will be handled just like any other Java objects. On our projects we use pure Groovy POGO (Plain Old Groovy Objects), which is much cleaner than the Java counterparts and do not encounter any anomalies or unexpected behavior when marshaling or unmarshaling to XML or JSON.